# What's the best way to attach 1 motor to 2 separate wheels on an electric skateboard?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, design

I am in the process of building an electric skateboard. I have all the electronics working and now it's time to put together my skateboard. The problem I am having is that I only have 1 motor and there are 2 wheels on both sides of the skateboard that I need to attach a motor to.

This means I have 3 options to attach the motor to the wheels:

1. I can get wheels that are on the same axle and rotate it with a 1 pulley so both wheels are connected together.
2. I can use a pulley system so that I have both of the wheels connected to 2 separate pulleys which are then connected to another gear / pulley that is connected to the motor and rotates them both.
3. I can attach a pulley to only one wheel and attach the other side to the motor and only rotate one of the wheels.

I am thinking about doing option 1 or 3 because option 2 seems pretty complex and I don't have enough room on the skateboard. If I go with option 1 i'm curious if the skateboard could even turn? I read that when a skateboard is turning the outer wheel rotates faster then the inner wheel, but if they are on the same axle then they would be rotating at the same speed right? My common sense tells me yes it will be able to rotate, but what's the physics behind using the same axle, rather than allowing the 2 wheels to turn separately from each other?

If I go with option 3 will my skateboard always be leaning towards the side with the motor because only 1 wheel is being rotated by the motor? Or will it drive straight? What's the pros and cons of option 1 vs option 3? Or maybe option 2 would be the best?

Comment: classic reason for a differential...

Comment: There are no good solutions befitting the simplicity of a skateboard